# js svg object refere

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I got a problem. I did a scetch with another program and saved it as svg.
Now i want to include the file on a website.
I created a div gave it an id and loading the svg file with js in that div.
Now i want to animate the svg, but i cant reference the svg object added to the div with getElementById. 
I just pull a Null Object.


My index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
       href="css/main.css" />

    <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fire_animation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="middleFire"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    fireInit();

});

$(window).on("load", function(){

    fireAnimation();

});
```

fire_animation.js

```
fireInit = function(){
    $("#middleFire").load("res/fire_all_finish.svg");
}

fireAnimation = function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("middleFireSrc"));
}
```

MiddleFireSrc is the id of the svg element in the other file

thanks for heelp :)

Comment: What element is `middleFireSrc`?

Answer (score 0):

The window "load" event fires when the page loads.  It won't be firing when the SVG loads.

However the jQuery `load()` method can take a callback function for when the load is complete.

Try this:

```
fireInit = function(){
    $("#middleFire").load("res/fire_all_finish.svg", fireAnimation);
}
```